# how to make clean/fancy URL?

Tags: php, asp.net, .net, apache, iis-7

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?page=articles
```

This URL is not clean and I know using some mechanism it is converted into something like this

```
http://www.example.com/articles/
```

it is now easy to remember, search spiders(google/bing) can pick it and so on.
**I want to know how to make URLs fancy/clean in php(apache) and .net(IIS 7).
provide the reference link if answer is bulky.**
thank you.

Comment: okay. i dint know it is called URL re-writing. thanks

Comment: Look into `.htaccess` and more specifically `Rewrite`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In asp.net it is called routing. For Asp.net MVC it is defalt machanism and IIS7 fully supports it.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)